# Ubuntu 12.10 Microsoft Surface Pro Wifi wpa_supplicant.conf Problem

Tags: wireless, surface

I followed the awesome guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu/265659#265659) to dual boot Ubuntu on my surface pro but I'm stuck at making wireless work.  The network I am trying to connect to is unsecured so I am a little lost at what to put in the wpa_supplicant.conf file. This is the code to put for an encrypted network

```
ctrl_interface_group=0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
scan_ssid=1
ssid="mySid"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
psk="passwordGoesWhere?"
```

What exactly do I put for psk and key_mgmt since it is unsecured?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `key_mgmt=NONE`, and you can comment out or remove the `psk=""` line.