# Problems with Windows 8/Ubuntu 13.04 Dualboot Surface Pro

Tags: 13.04, wireless, grub2, windows, surface

I've been having this problem this whole day and it's been killing me... I'm following [Dual boot Surface Pro with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu) this guide to dual boot my Microsoft Surface Pro with Ubuntu 13.04.

The main problem I have is that the WiFi doesn't work and I do not have a Ethernet port on this device. I get to the point in the guide where he installs boot-repair, the problem is that he downloads it off the internet... which I have no access too.

Just so you know, I am have Ubuntu on my device installed under a partition. I did the try and install Ubuntu option, installed it and now I'm "continuing testing", simply just trying to get Grub2 to work, so I can switch between partitions. WiFi would be a plus too, but that shouldn't be difficult once I get this out of the way.

So I've tried a few things... I downloaded the tar.gz of boot-repair on my other partition and grabbed it from there. There is absolutely no documentation that tells me how to manually compile it, so I got stuck there.

I tried to do step 7 on the tutorial, download the two .deb files and get them on to this OS from my Windows partition and manually install them using the "sudo dpkg -i package.deb" command. The .deb's installed by my internet still isn't working. Even when I double click them so I can use the Ubuntu Software Center, the install button is just grayed out.

I tried using EasyBCD on my Window partition to set up a way to access my Ubuntu Partition from boot up but I just get a WBM error and then Windows 8 boots after.
I just want to get Grub2 working so I can actually tackle this WiFi issue without constantly having to boot off this annoying flash drive. Is there anyone I can get Grub2 or any way to switch between partitions working without WiFi?

I appreciate all the help, after a few beers and about 8 hours of working on this straight I'm about to throw my Surface out the window.
Cheers.

Comment: I can try to help you compile the tar.gz if you're still working on this problem

Comment: First off, I don't own a Surface Pro; I am in the process of buying one for my daughter. What is holding me back is the fact that I have yet to read from someone who has successfully dual booted it with Ubuntu Linux. While my laptop dual boots Win 7 Pro full and Ubuntu Linux 13.04 (both 64 bit), I bumped into the same issue you described. The way I solved the problem was through the use of wired (Ethernet) lan. Have you considered using a (micro)-USB-to-ethernet adapter? Experience has taught me that there are times the only way to get Ubuntu working properly is to get a physical connection up