# Dual boot MS Surface PRO issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, surface

I'm trying to successfully get my Surface Pro to dual boot Ubuntu, alongside windows 8.1, using a 128gb SD card

I came across a guide ([Dual boot Surface Pro with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu/265659#265659)) and followed it, but there are a couple things I'm not clear about:

1. What is the purpose of the initial resizing of the windows partition. (Unsure whether the guide originally was intended to be used with just the internal HDD)
2. The guide tells you to disable secure boot. Is the intent that you will never enable secure boot again? I only ask because I thought Ubuntu 14.10 was supposed to be compatible with secure boot.
3. Whenever I boot the machine, it defaults to a command line interface for grub. I have to type exit, and then it sometimes goes into the grub GUI, but not always, it sometimes bypasses grub and boots up Windows.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I didn't know how to direct the question to the guy who posted the solution, and didn't have enough reputation points to comment on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes the guide is intended to be used with the internal HDD. So you need to partition your disk to make some room for linux prior to install it.
2. Disabling Secure boot is required in this tutorial as it doesn't show how to enable it again. [This blog post talks about re-enabling the secure boot](http://blog.davidelner.com/dual-booting-ubuntu-14-10-on-the-surface-pro-3/). But his solution doesn't seem perfect. I personaly do not concider this as a primary issue, and I am running without Secure boot, although, when a better solution will emerge I'll probably apply it.
3. About your issue of landing on a grub command line before having the actual grub customized UI. Hmm, you should probably focus on getting the classical grub running. Once you've secured this, you can optional dive deeper to get the Graphical UI running. This will help you sort out if it's the final patches that are involved in the issue you are facing or if it is a deeper issue.