# No Windows Option on Lubuntu Dual Boot on Surface Pro 3

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, surface

I installed Lubuntu alongside a preexisting windows 8.1 install on my Surface Pro 3. Lubuntu was installed fine - but when I boot up - I dont see an option to boot into Windows.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11291738/

I tried - running boot-fix - which added the Recovery Windows partitions - but not the main one (206 gb ntfs) - sdf4 . It says that sdf4 unknown filesystem.

I didnt disable bitlocker encryption - and I am assuming that is the problem. No idea how to go about doing that now - or what to do next.

Any suggestions? thanks a lot!

There are plenty of questions on askubuntu.com - regarding Dual boot option not showing up. I have been through most of them - and they do not seem to tackle this issue of the primary Windows Partition sdf4 - not being readable or not having a boot sector for some reason. So this is not a duplicate.

Also I will add that Touchpad doesn't work although Lubuntu is on kernel 3.19
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual boot Surface Pro with Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu)