# Remove grub2 from Surface Pro 1

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, surface

i installed Ubuntu on my Surface Pro following this guide:
[Dual boot Surface Pro with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu)
But now I want to remove Grub2 and switch back to the regular Bootloader to be able to enter the Windows Recovery and to install the Windows 10 Preview. 
But how can I remove Grub2? I think when I just delete the Ubuntu partition it won't work, right?