# Fail to access boot from USB mode after "bitlocker enabled" interruption

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu OS on a Windows Surface Book. I was able to access the Boot from USB menu and follow all isntructions until installation was interrupted by the "bitlocker enabled" issue. I have since disabled bitlocker encryption on my device, however my device will now no longer enter boot from USB mode. I have tried flashing the disk image to another USB, disabling Secure Boot, changing the boot order of my PC. With each of these solutions, my PC will either boot in Windows or remain stuck on the boot loading screen.

It seems some Linux libraries had been installed prior to the bitlocker pop-up as I now have a Linux directory in File Explorer.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I get around this issue or what might be happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What model Surface Book? Many require additional settings. What version of Ubuntu? It needs to be more recent than when system was first released. You may have separate setting for allow USB boot or full USB support as allowing USB boot is also not secure. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_3

Comment: I'm using a Surface Book 2, trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.3. In the wiki link I've tried each of these methods however my device will not load past the windows logo

Comment: Some older threads, would expect newer Ubuntu would work better. Surface Pro2 mega thread:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183946 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2209247 & Surface Pro Ubuntu install:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365819 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309963&p=13424798#post13424798 & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu & https://www.phoronix.com/news/Microsoft-Surface-SAM-Linux

Comment: I've experimented with some other Linux distros. It seems I can load arch and mint easily. I don't know why the Ubuntu disk image just stopped working but I guess I'm just going to work with another distro for now.