# Ubuntu on Lenovo YOGA 11

Tags: system-installation

I would like to know if it is possible to run Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga Ideapad 11 (which is different from the Yoga 13 version and the Yoga 11s version)? Also, if it is not possible to replace the Windows RT with Ubuntu, can I run Ubuntu from a USB? Do you know when the tablet version of Ubuntu will be available and if it would be possible to run it on my Yoga 11?

Windows RT is a horrible OS and I want to remove it asap.

Thank you for your help,
Joseph

Comment: If I'm correct, Windows RT is for ARM devices (non-x86), so it's more like a tablet/phone inside as far as the CPU is concerned. That is the first challenge. Then there's enforced secure boot: [Can Ubuntu run on a Microsoft Surface with Windows RT?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206141/88802) So I guess it will be very hard to nearly impossible to run Ubuntu. Perhaps by creating custom initrd's and some tricks like described in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Server/Install will make it possible. But I would really need the same hardware to provide an answer.

Comment: Yep: CPU=NVIDIA® Tegra 3, RAM=2GB, GPU=NVIDIA® GeForce® Integrated GFX

Answer (score 1):

Phoronix discussed [the steps required for a different Tegra 3](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA3MjQ) device, so it's doable, but it is by no means as easy as an x86 or X86-64 install with a standardized distro.

Also, *Rivera151* [reported elsewhere](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2095076&page=2):

> The MS agreement with manufacturers of Windows RT tablets specifically
>   states that the manufacturer may NOT provide means to access the UEFI
>   settings (i.e. like BIOS settings, you would set the boot
>   disk/partition here). Thus, there will not be a way of booting to an
>   alternate partition until that agreement gets fixed.

Therefore, I am not optimistic, contrary to my earlier optimism.