# Ubuntu on Surface RT?

Tags: system-installation, uefi, secure-boot, surface

A continuation of [Can Ubuntu run on a Microsoft Surface with Windows RT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206141/can-ubuntu-run-on-a-microsoft-surface-with-windows-rt)

> **Regarding the Duplicate Votes:**
>
> Technology has changed. Now that Ubuntu natively supports UEFI and Secure Boot, this question can be re-opened. In Ubuntu Release 12.10 (the newest possible version at the time of the "duplicate's" writing, `shim` was unstable and didn't support a number of SecureBoot features. Now that `shim` has had over two years to mature, this question can be opened again. **The base difference is that my question was asked in a time where `shim` and Ubuntu are more mature, and may work.**

---

As we now know, Ubuntu natively supports Secure Boot and UEFI. Is there now a way to force Ubuntu onto the Surface RT? I'd assume it's possible, but I'm not sure how.

From what I've read on other sites and answers, this would be impossible because of Linux's inability to support Secure Boot. But, Ubuntu's `shim` should be able to bypass that, right?

Is it possible? And if so, how do we do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Ubuntu run on a Microsoft Surface with Windows RT?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206141/can-ubuntu-run-on-a-microsoft-surface-with-windows-rt)

Comment: Have you tried it? If so please share your experiences (difficulties, success if any)

Comment: @ElderGeek Nope... I'm planning on getting one and I want to see if it's possible first.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://www.geek.com/microsoft/linux-users-rejoice-heres-ubuntu-on-the-surface-pro-3-1594864/

Comment: Take an Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB into a Microsoft Store and try booting it. ;)  They might laugh at you while escorting you out the door, or you will get your answer if it can boot the latest version of Ubuntu.  You could try some other brick and mortar store if you don't want to attract as much attention.